# Convert free space LVM to ext

Tags: partition, lvm

Can I convert Free  space in a LVM partition to a ext3 partition?
If I run `pvs`:

```
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  297,11g 30,02g
```

So I have 30GB unused, I would like to take them out of the LVM partition to convert it in ext3 partition. Is it possible? Or is it better to just partition these 30 GB in a new Logical Volume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have LVM set up, just use that — you can either extend an existing LV (and the filesystem it hosts), or create a new LV. See [`lvextend(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvextend.8.html) and [`lvcreate(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvcreate.8.html) for details.

Comment: Will there be any differences if I use a new LV, or if this new partition is an ext3 partition? I would like this partition to be encrypted with the help of LUKS, is it possible in both cases?

Comment: If you create a new partition instead of a LV, you won't be able to manage it using LVM (resize it etc.); what's more, reducing your PV to create a new partition would be rather complex. You can use LUKS on top of a partition or a LV, it works just as well in both cases. Again, since you already have LVM set up, just use that, don't try to use partitions directly...